# How to return a String representation of an object in Java

Tags: java

I created a shape object in java which has attributes color, corners and name.
I then have a method create shape that return a Shape object. I have for instance create a circle. What I need to do is return a string of the object for example `shape.toString()` needs to be:

```
Circle[c=Blue,cnr=0]:cirleName
```

but I am getting:

```
com.shape.model.Circle@64fa8cc6
```

Comment: Override the `toString` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need only to rewrite the method `toString()`. Please verify the signature of this method.

```
public String toString() {
    return "Circle[c=" + color + " ,cnr= " + cnr + "]:" + cirleName;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. This works! is there anyway to get the class name of the object as Circle and not class com.shape.model.Circle because at the moment I am returning as class com.shape.model.Circle[c=Blue,cnr=0]:circleName

Comment: To get the class name without a package you can use the following code Circle.class.getSimpleName()